# $\sin(x+\pi/3)=2\sin x \sin(\pi/3)$ show that $11\tan x=a+b\sqrt{3} $ ; $a,b$ are elements of positive integers

Tags: trigonometry

> If $x$ satisfies the equation $\sin\left(x+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)=2\sin x\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)$, show that $11\tan x=a+b\sqrt{3}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$
>   
> <sub>[[src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIPC6.png)]</sub>

I've tried using the sine addition thing and converting the radians in to their values but I couldn't seem to get the 11 infront of the $\tan x $.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

$$\implies\frac{\sin(A+B)}{\sin A\sin B}=\frac1{\tan A}+\frac1{\tan B}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [sine of sum identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) in conjunction with the [special values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Special_values_in_trigonometric_functions) $\sin \left(\pi /3\right) =\sqrt{3}/2$, $\cos \left( \pi /3\right) =1/2$ to get the
equivalent equation

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\sin x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x=\sqrt{3}\sin x\text{.}
\end{equation*}

Simplify  and divide the new equation by $\cos x$. The rest is algebra manipulation, in which you need to rationalize the denominator of the resulting fraction.